# Selectizeinput inputs be mutually exclusive R Shiny

Tags: r, input, shiny

I have to use multiple selectizeinputs for the same variable. When i choose one category one bla1, the category should excluded in bla2. How do i archieve that?Is there an option to link two selectizeinputs?

```
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30),
         selectizeInput("bla1", "muh", choices = faithful$waiting, multiple = TRUE),
         selectizeInput("bla2", "muh2", choices = faithful$waiting, multiple = TRUE)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: you will have to create the `selectizeInput` in the server via `renderUI` and include some logic for the filtering.

Answer (score 2):

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      selectizeInput("bla1", "muh", choices = faithful$waiting, multiple = TRUE),
      htmlOutput("bla2")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {



  output$bla2 <- renderUI({
    ## filter choices to anything NOT selected by bla1
    choices <- faithful$waiting[!faithful$waiting %in% input$bla1]
    selected <- input$bla2
    selectizeInput("bla2", "muh2", choices = choices, multiple = TRUE, selected = selected)
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This code was posted by a guy and it is the best solution. The only thing is that when I click in "input$bla2" i lose the focus on the field when i enter a value. Probably because it renders again every time. Anyone an idea how to overcome that problem?

Comment: Its not a real mutual exlcusion though, `bla1` will always have full options and determine the options of `bla2`. You mean the focus on 'bla2', as after every select the dropdown closes? Probably some css or JS could do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define your input on server side.
And then, just do a little trick to get the `avaiable` options:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      uiOutput("bla1_ui"),  # here just for defining your ui
      uiOutput("bla2_ui")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  # and here you deal with your desired input
  output$bla1_ui <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("bla1", "muh", choices = faithful$waiting, multiple = TRUE)
  })

  output$bla2_ui <- renderUI({

    avaiable <- faithful$waiting
    if(!is.null(input$bla1))
      avaiable <- faithful$waiting[-which(faithful$waiting %in% input$bla1)]

    selectizeInput("bla2", "muh2", choices=avaiable, multiple = TRUE)
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This will re-render bla2, when bla1 is invoked again. Probably a `reactive`/`reactiveVal`/`reactiveValues` might be helpful?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There is an error that if you don't choose a bla1, bla2 is empty, but I'll correct it with a condition for setting the variable `avaiable`

Comment: Select something from the first selectInput, then select something from the second selectInput and then again from the first. You will see, that the selected variable from the second selectInput is gone.

Comment: Hmm you're right, also right about `reactive` fixing this. But I don't understand `reactive` very well, when I use it is by trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation with `isolate()`, I think I have found a pretty solution. You can try it with:

```
shiny::runGist("https://gist.github.com/netique/499c0117f092d43980b1c8ea52671499")
```

Source:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("left", "left",
      choices = LETTERS[1:10],
      multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE, size = 10
    ),
    selectInput("right", "right",
      choices = LETTERS[1:10],
      multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE, size = 10
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(
      input$right,
      {
        updateSelectInput(
          inputId = "left",
          choices = setdiff(LETTERS[1:10], isolate(input$right)),
          selected = isolate(input$left)
        )
      }
    )
    observeEvent(
      input$left,
      {
        updateSelectInput(
          inputId = "right",
          choices = setdiff(LETTERS[1:10], isolate(input$left)),
          selected = isolate(input$right)
        )
      }
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but note that you actually don't need `isolate` in this case, as `observeEvent` only reacts to the condition (i.e. `input$left` or `input$right`)