# restrict combinations of input selectizeInput in r shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a small app to summarize some data. my results table has the value of a number of categories that sum to a given total. Now I would like users to be able to input different categories and get the sum of the statistics of those categories OR show them the total of all categories (so selecting all the categories gives the same as just selecting the total). To make the app look a bit cleaner I would like to simply use a single `selectizeInput`. However, that would mean that if the user selects the category `total` they should not be able to select any of the other 3 categories and if any of the 3 categories is selected `total` should be deselected. Otherwise, if the user selects all inputs including the total the sum sum to 2*`Total` (in my example 20 instead of 10).

Small example (based on https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html)

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("Total", "A", "B", "C"),
                 sum_res = c(10, 5, 3, 2))
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(title = 'Selectize examples',
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectizeInput(
                      'e2',
                      '2. Multi-select',
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      selected = "Total",
                      choices = df$x
                    )
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    helpText('Output of the examples in the left:'),
                    verbatimTextOutput('ex_out'),
                    verbatimTextOutput('sum')
                  )
                ))


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ex_out <- renderPrint({
    str(list(input$e2))
  })
  
  output$sum <- renderPrint({
    df %>%
      filter(x %in% input$e2) %>%
      summarise(sum = sum(sum_res))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is somewhat related, but not exactly the same as [Selectizeinput inputs be mutually exclusive R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590275/selectizeinput-inputs-be-mutually-exclusive-r-shiny).

Ideally this solution would be in the custom javascript within the `selectizeInput()`, but could also be serverside.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to ignore other selections when `Total` is selected.  Try this

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 sum_res = c(5, 3, 2))
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(title = 'Selectize examples',
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectizeInput(
                      'e2',
                      '2. Multi-select',
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      selected = "Total",
                      choices = c("Total",unique(df$x))
                    )
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    helpText('Output of the examples in the left:'),
                    verbatimTextOutput('ex_out'),
                    verbatimTextOutput('sum')
                  )
                ))


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ex_out <- renderPrint({
    str(list(input$e2))
  })
  
  output$sum <- renderPrint({
    if ("Total" %in% input$e2 | length(input$e2)==3) df1 <- df
    else  df1 <- df %>% filter(x %in% input$e2) 
    df1 %>% summarise(sum = sum(sum_res))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, server-side that does the exact right thing, but from a UI perspective, that is not very intuitive.